# Why doesn't initializer work with properties returning list<t>?

Tags: c#, .net, initializer

Couldn't find an answer to this question. It must be obvious, but still.

I try to use initializer in this simplified example:

```
    MyNode newNode = new MyNode 
    {
        NodeName = "newNode",
        Children.Add(/*smth*/) // mistake is here
    };
```

where Children is a property for this class, which returns a list. And here I come across a mistake, which goes like 'Invalid initializer member declarator'.

What is wrong here, and how do you initialize such properties? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That's not initializing a property. You're calling a method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't call methods like that in object initializers - you can only set properties or fields, rather than call methods. However in this case you probably *can* still use object and collection initializer syntax:

```
MyNode newNode = new MyNode
{
    NodeName = "newNode",
    Children = { /* values */ }
};
```

Note that this won't try to assign a new value to `Children`, it will call `Children.Add(...)`, like this:

```
var tmp = new MyNode();
tmp.NodeName = "newNode":
tmp.Children.Add(value1);
tmp.Children.Add(value2);
...
MyNode newNode = tmp;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because the children property is not initialized

```
MyNode newNode = new MyNode 
    {
        NodeName = "newNode",
        Children = new List<T> (/*smth*/)
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're executing a method, not assigning a value

Answer (score 2):

The field initializer syntax can only be used for setting fields and properties, not for calling methods.  If `Children` is `List<T>`, you might be able to accomplish it this way, by also including the list initializer syntax:

```
T myT = /* smth */

MyNode newNode = new MyNode 
{
    NodeName = "newNode",
    Children = new List<T> { myT }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is not setting a value in the initialiser:

```
Children.Add(/*smth*/) // mistake is here
```

It's trying to access a member of a field (a not-yet-initialised one, too.)

Answer (score 2):

Initializers is just to initialize the properties, not other actions.

You are not trying to initialize the Children list, you are trying to add something to it.

`Children = new List<smth>()` is initializing it.