# Setting a C# List property while initializing its parent object

Tags: c#

Suppose we have the following class;

```
public class WithInit
{
    public List<string> List;

    public WithInit()
    {
         List = new List<string> { "one" };
    }
}
```

Then we do this;

```
var withInit = new WithInit { List = { "two", "three" } };
Assert.AreEqual(3, withInit.List.Count);
```

Jon Skeet points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6385835/469777) that `.Add(...)` is called.  Although its clearly happening, does the C# specification define this functionality?

Now, if we have something like this;

```
public class NoInit
{
    public List<string> List;
}
```

Then;

```
var one = new NoInit { List = new List<string> { "two", "three" } }; // works
var two = new NoInit { List = { "two", "three" } }; // compiles, but runtime error
```

The second one will throw a `NullReferenceException`, and I can deduce that its because `List<>` was never initialised.  However, these lines are then doing two different things - the first assigns a reference to the `new`'d `List<>`, but the second one determines that a non-null reference already exists and so executes a `.Add(...)`.

How/why does c# do this?

Comment: I've answered your question in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: So what's your actual question? You've provided the answers yourself. The two lines do different things for sure: The first initializes and assigns, the second one just assigns and hence faces a null reference exception.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel your answer on the other question certainly helps me understand it.  However i was hoping for a reference to the specification also - do you know one?

Comment: C# 5.0 language specification section  **§7.6.10.2** talks about that. It is called nested object initializer.